# p4 describe for multiple changelists

Tags: perforce

I want to redirect the output pf  "p4 describe" for a set of Changelists, into a xls file.

As I saw the syntax for p4 describe, we can only give a single changelist with "p4 describe" for ex: p4 describe -df .

Could you please help me get p4 describe for multiple CLs?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the syntax for 'p4 describe', from 'p4 help describe':

```
describe -- Display a changelist description

p4 describe [-d<flags> -s -S -f -O] changelist# ...
```

Note that '...' at the end. That means that you can pass multiple arguments.

So, for example,

```
p4 describe -df 1704 1722 1903
```

works fine, and describes each changelist, in turn, one after the next, in a single command.

Now, as to the bit about trying to put this in a xls file, I'm confused, because I'm not sure what sort of xls file you're talking about. The output of describe doesn't seem very useful as a spreadsheet, to me.